# How to detect keyboard event while chrome window is created?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, keyboard-events

I want to show my Chrome extension popup in a window through the click of a keyboard command and hide it once the respective modifier keys are released. It works, but it's not fast enough taking 150ms from triggering to adding the event listeners that detects the modifier-key release. 
Problem: the release won't be detected if the user releases the keys too fast.

I suppose there are many ways to improve loading time; or at least I hope. 
Therefore I am more interested in key state detection.

**Is it possible to detect the state of a modifier-key without an event?** I already tried dispatching a keyboard event myself in order to read the modifier key state, but that was a stupid idea...

**How to listen to key events during the transition phase when a window is created?** Using a content script could work, but since I use global commands, Chrome may not even be focused.

Basically that's how I do it:
using 
`chrome.windows.create({'url': chrome.extension.getURL("popup.html"),'type': 'popup', ...` to show and
`window.addEventListener('keyup', function (event) {});` to listen.

Comment: The only solution for global keys is to write a separate utility that uses system API to monitor the key state and reports it to your extension via nativeMessaging.

Comment: Writing a separate program for each OS and integrating it via nativeMessaging sounds like lots of work. But I'll consider since I'll need it anyway for sth. else.

Comment: **Solution** for myself. 1. Create a tab with your content, but keep it pinned in the background. 2. On click of shortcut, create a new window with the existing tab by setting ``'tabId': popupTab.id``. The whole process is insanely fast and you can detect even the fastest keyboard events, since html, css, js scripts eventshandlers are already examined and active.

Comment: I've also tried creating the popup from a tab (or just hiding the popup behind other windows, instead of recreating it each time), but it still doesn't seem to help if you press and release the keys of the shortcut too close together. In that case, Chrome doesn't seem to fire any events at all in the popup, even though it triggered your code to open it. (This seems to only be a problem on Windows, as I haven't been able to recreate it on macOS.)

Comment: Hey @jdunning, I am MartinLichtblau (the one who introduced this feature to you). What exactly doesn't work in your extension? Can you send me the github issue, so we can continue there? It works flawlessly since years on my Windows system. Perhaps I can help.